# Accordion active don't work on first load

Tags: jquery

when it loads first time i am trying to active first div but it makes all div active except of first. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Abdul786/ym2E3/1/) it is on jsfiddle.

```
$(".accordion > span").click(function(){
  $('.accordion > span').removeClass('active');

  $(this).addClass('active');
    if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $('.accordion > div').slideUp(300);
    }
    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
});

var animationIsOff = $.fx.off;
$.fx.off = true;
$('.accordion > span:eq(0)').click()
$.fx.off = animationIsOff;
```

here is HTML

```
<div class="accordion">
    <span>Accor 1</span>
    <div>
Content here
    </div>
</div>

<div class="accordion">
    <span>Accor 2</span>
    <div>
Content here
    </div>
</div>

<div class="accordion">
    <span>Accor 2</span>
    <div>
Content here
    </div>
</div>
```

any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close.

All you need to do is add `active` class for first span.

```
$('.accordion > span:eq(0)').addClass('active');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ym2E3/2/

**OR**

You can `hide` other `div`.

```
$('.accordion > span:not(:eq(0))').next('div').css('display','none');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ym2E3/9/

Comment: Thanks for your Answer but i am trying to active first div not all divs.

Comment: @Ask4Tec see my second option i have just edited with example.

Comment: Thank you very very much.
this is what i was trying to do.
thanks again.